# Stack pop operation using linked list

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

Elements in the list are 6495 i.e, first 5 was pushed then 9 and so on. Now I want to pop 5(I know that first 6 should be according to FILO)i.e, in the reverse order. The element popped is 5 both in the first and second time I am doing a pop operation.
Temp is a local variable so even if i free it in pop function it will not be freed in the main if i were to display the elements in main?Is that true?But in any case I did my cout in the pop operation itself but it's still not working? If I use display fn. after pop it goes into an infinite loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

struct stackNode
{
int data;
struct stackNode *next;
};
int is_emp(struct stackNode* head)
{
if(head==NULL)
    return 0;
else
    return 1;
}
void push(struct stackNode** head,int data)
{
struct stackNode* current =(struct stackNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct stackNode));
current->data=data;
current->next=NULL;
current->next=*head;
*head=current;
}
int pop(struct stackNode** head)
{
    int ele;
    struct stackNode* temp=*head;
    if(is_emp(*head)==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Underflow";
        return INT_MIN;
    }
    else
    {
     while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
    temp=temp->next;
    }
  cout<<"Popped ele:"<<temp->data<<endl;
  free(temp);
  temp=NULL;   
 }
}
void disp(struct stackNode* head)
{
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<head->data<<endl;
        head=head->next;
    }
}

int main()
{

    struct stackNode* head=NULL;
    push(&head,5);
    push(&head,9);
    push(&head,4);
    push(&head,6);
    disp(head);
    pop(&head);
    disp(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `free` in C++ code? Why are you not using one of the standard templates to do this?

Comment: @EdHeal It doesn't cause any problem.(not a warning also). What should I use then?

Comment: @Rooney10 At least you don't allocate anything, so what should be `free()`'d there?

Comment: @Rooney10 `new/delete` for C++, `malloc/free` for C

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ U r right but what should i use in place of free. The problem is in the free part, temp is a local variable and also we didn't allocate any memory for it but using temp as a global variable also I am getting the incorrect output so the problem must be in free part

Comment: Just don't use it for local variables. But where are you allocating space for your `stackNode` instances?

Comment: @EdHeal Even if i use delete this doesn't work

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I updated my prg.. U can see the allocation

Answer (score 0):

```
if(temp!=NULL)
{
    ele=temp->data;
    temp=temp->next;
}
free(temp);
```

Here, you are making changes with the temp variable not with the head.
So the head pointer still points to 6 when you see it in main.

Instead of temp, make changes in the head pointer.

Comment: Yup but i can't use *head in place of temp in that case the linkedlist will be lost. I am using temp to traverse to the last element i.e, 5 to free it but as it is a local variable the changes are not reflected outside. I don't know what to write in place of temp

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the code that you are looking forward. Note the use of references.

```
#include <limits>

struct stackNode
{
    stackNode *next;
    int data;
    stackNode(stackNode *n, int d) : next(n), data(d) {}
};

void push(stackNode* &head,int data)
{
    head =new stackNode(head, data);
}

int pop(stackNode* &head)
{
    if (head == NULL) {
       return std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    } else {
        int ret = head -> data;
        stackNode *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
        return ret;
    }
}

int main()
{
    stackNode* head = NULL;
    push(head,5);
    push(head,9);
    push(head,4);
    push(head,6);
 //   disp(head);
    pop(head);
//    disp(head);
    return 0;
}
```